# Group Text question

Tags: applications

I use message+ for text. I am stuck in 2 group texts from hell. I didn't ask to be included, I just was & now I can't get out!
Is there anything I can do to leave these group texts? If I factor reset my phone will it stop? Do I have to go to the extreme & change my number?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using another messaging app instead of message+.i believe it would be much better than a factory reset. You could try wiping the App data (message+). Tell me if it helps